# Sticky header for horizontal scroll

Tags: flutter

Plugin: `sticky_headers` https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sticky_headers/sticky_headers.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Widget> timeHeaders = new List<Widget>();
  Map<int, List<Widget>> roomRow = new Map<int, List<Widget>>();

  double fontSize = 18;
  double leadingWidth = 120;
  double tileWidth = 84; // CHANGE THIS IF NEEDED
  double tileHeight = 30;
  double tileBorderWidth = 2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    timeHeaders.add(
      new Container(
        height: tileHeight,
        width: leadingWidth,
      ),
    );

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      timeHeaders.add(
        new Container(
          height: tileHeight,
          width: tileWidth,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.grey[400],
            border: Border.all(
              color: Colors.black,
              width: 2,
            ),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              '$i',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
      roomRow[i + 1] = [
        Container(
          height: tileHeight,
          width: leadingWidth,
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'HEADER$i',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ];

      roomRow[i + 1].add(Container(
        height: tileHeight,
        width: 75,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.lightGreen[300],
          border: Border.all(
            color: Colors.black,
            width: tileBorderWidth,
          ),
        ),
        child: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(1),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'x',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 10,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('header'),
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: (timeHeaders.length.toDouble() - 1) * tileWidth +
                      leadingWidth,
                  child: StickyHeader(
                    header: Row(children: timeHeaders),
                    content: ListView.separated(
                      separatorBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                          Divider(),
                      itemCount: 21,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return index == 0
                            ? Container(height: tileHeight)
                            : Row(children: roomRow[index]);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

(I know there's a render error in the log but it doesn't affect the functionality, my main app works fine)

Basically, if you scroll vertically (up and down), the gray boxes are stickied to the top. I want to do the same with the HEADERs on the left, when scrolling horizontally (left to right). So if I scroll all the way to the right, the HEADERs should still be there

GIF: https://i.imgur.com/l7TZMWc.mp4

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this? If so could you share your answer thank you.

Comment: @F-1 not yet. I haven't touched this app for a few months now

Comment: Any reason why this library doesn't work horizontally?

Comment: **sliver_sticky_header** works for horizontal scrolls.